# What's the difference between $\frac{\delta}{dt}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}$?

Tags: calculus, notation

I have read the few questions on calculi notation, particularly the notations on partial and total derivatives. My question seems to have not been answered, or at least not brought to my attention. If there has been a similar thread, please direct it to me. Thanks :)

Anyways, my question is simple: what's the difference between $\frac{\delta}{dt}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}$? In other words:

$$
\frac{\delta x}{\delta y} \text{ is } \frac{dx}{dy} \text{?}
$$

Comment: Are you sure you mean
$$\frac{\delta}{dt}$$
and not
$$\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\quad ?$$

Comment: or $\delta/\delta t$? $\delta/ dt$ seems rather strange.

Comment: @Brady: I've never seen $\delta$ used for a derivative notation. Note that $\delta$ (`\delta`) and $\partial$ (`\partial`) are different symbols.

Comment: @ZevChonoles, I understand, but I do have a vague recollection of seeing such notation, though it must be rare. Take for instance the divergence of notations in physics treatments, for instance $\int dx f$.

Comment: @Trainor, I think you guys are right – they are used more in physics.

Comment: @Yuruk, yes, I would find it even more strange to see mixing of notation such as $\delta/dt$. Also, can you provide a reference to where you saw $\delta$ used this way? If it exists, I am wondering if it should be interpreted as $\partial$ or $d$, if either.

Comment: Notations like $\delta L/\delta f$ are commonly used in the [calculus of variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) to denote the derivative of a functional (i.e., a function whose domain is a space of functions) with respect to the unknown function.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65724/2451

Comment: $\delta$ could mean variation in a functional or it could mean non-zero change in a function.

Comment: Similarly to the above comment, it reminds one of $\frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta x}$ as the [average rate of change](https://calcworkshop.com/derivatives/average-rate-of-change-calculus/) or [discrete derivative](https://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/DCalc.pdf), but with $\delta$

Answer (score 3):

**In thermodynamics** we conventionnally use $\delta Q$ insead of $\partial Q$ or $dQ$ to make it clear that the heat $Q$ is not a *thermodynamical-state* unlike the *temperature T, entropy S, enthalpy H, total_energy U, Pressure P*. For a thermodynamical state $X$ you can write $dX$ or $\partial X$, but for a quantity which is not a *thermo-state* we dont use the conventional differential signs $\partial$ or $d$.
In other words in thermodynamics writing $$\frac{\delta Q}{dt}$$ means that you are calculating the total time derivative of a quantitiy which is not as *thermo-state* <=> Q doesn't respect Schwarz's equality.

**In analytical mechanics** $\delta$ represents the differential of *virtual quantitie*s like virtual displacement $\delta \vec{r}$, virtual work $\delta W$, etc...

But of cours those notations are conventions between physicists.

Comment: $\mathrm d X$ is defined because $X$ is a function on the manifold $M$, right? And $Q$ is not a function on $M$.

Comment: I never thought in terms of Riemannian geometry but yes you're right X is a function on a manifold M, but Q is not, that's exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

We have a very good explanation on the $\delta$ notation in the **Chapter 6** of the book **"Classical Dynamics"** by ***Thornton and Marion***. Despite the fact that it is a book for physicists you will see the explanation of such a notation by means of the calculus of variations. It's difference from the other simbols for derivatives is also covered there.