# Notation of derivatives...

Tags: calculus, derivatives, notation

I asked my teacher the difference between this notations.

(1) $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$
(2) $$\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}$$
(3) $$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

He told me that there is no difference.

I really don't think he's right...

**Question:**

**I think that (1) and (2) is more like the convention expressing the limit of a fraction.  (3) instead really represent de ratio of the increments of *y* and *x***

Am I right?

Comment: I don't know about (2), but I'd agree with you on (1) and (3).

Comment: Somewhat of a duplicate of [What's the difference between $\frac{\delta}{dt}$ and $\frac{d}{dt}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/396072/264)

Comment: @Haizum: Are you sure you mean $\dfrac{\delta y}{\delta x}$
and not
$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$?

Comment: I'd say that you are right on (2) as well, although it is primarily used to denote directional derivative for functions on infinite-dimensional spaces (in calculus of variations).

Comment: Here is a (somewhat) useful link with review of various notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation

Comment: @ZevChonoles, no, not really... can you explain a little more what are you thinking? ($\delta$ vs $\partial$)

Comment: @Haizum: I'm just asking because I have seen many people, unfamiliar with mathematical notation, to assume $\partial$ that $\delta$ are the same symbol (especially on a blackboard).

Comment: @ZevChonoles Well, in that case, I use de $\delta$ just as I saw in some text I have.  The other, really don`t know where to use it $(\partial)$ (Thank you for your comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically,

1. $\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the derivative (the slope of the tangent line);
2. $\displaystyle\frac{\delta y}{\delta x(t)}$ is a functional derivative where $y=y[x]$ is a functional of $x(t)$;
3. $\displaystyle\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ is the difference quotient (the slope of the secant line).